# I am getting the "'CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch'" error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, ssl-certificate, mqtt

I am trying to integrate the MQTT structure into my Flutter application, and I am getting the error 'CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(handshake.cc:393).' I provided a certificate that comes from MQTT itself, but no matter what I try, I can't get it accepted.

Here are my codes

```
  Future<void> initializeMQTTClient() async {
    _client = MqttServerClient(_host, '');
    final ByteData caByteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/ca.crt');
    final caCrt = caByteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;

    _client!.securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(caCrt);
   // _client!.securityContext.setTrustedCertificates('assets/ca.crt');
    _client!.port = 51883;
    _client!.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
    _client!.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
    _client!.secure = true;
    _client!.logging(on: true);
    _client!.connect('emirhan', 'deneme');
    _client!.onConnected = onConnected;
    _client!.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;

    final MqttConnectMessage connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
        .withClientIdentifier('test')
        .withWillTopic(
            'willtopic') // If you set this you must set a will message
        .withWillMessage('My Will message')
        .authenticateAs('emirhan', 'deneme')
        .startClean() // Non persistent session for testing
        .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
    print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto2 client connecting....');
    _client!.connectionMessage = connMess;
  }
```

I have used different codebases for various projects, but I am having difficulty making progress in Flutter for MQTT because there are not many resources available.

Comment: For now, use `_client!.onBadCertificate` to provide a function that always returns `true`. That should get you connecting. It will also allow you to print the server certificate to see why its CN doesn't match the hostname you are using to connect.

Comment: Edit the question to show the certificate details (CN, SAN) and what hostname you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

usually this means the hostname in the certificate is actually different than what you are trying to connect with. e.g. certificate is for localhost but host is randomname.com